# Does batch size matters at inference for a sematic segmentation model?

Tags: python, pytorch, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I’m trying to evaluate a semantic segmentation model on Pascal Voc 2012 dataset. I’m using the mIoU metric. I’m evaluating the model with different batch sizes. For example, I tried batch size = 1 and batch size = 16 and I got different mIoU. Especially, with batch size = 1, I take better mIoU than with batch size =16. Does batch size affects the performance on evaluation?

I actually compute the mean of the mIoUs of each sample when I set batch size = 1. On the other hand, when I set batch size = 16, I compute the mIoU over the current batch and then the mean over the total batches. From these two, i’m taking different results. Here is the code for the mIoU metric and the evaluation function

```
def mIoU(pred_mask, mask, smooth=1e-10, n_classes=21):
    with torch.no_grad():
        pred_mask = pred_mask.to("cpu").contiguous().view(-1)
        mask = mask.to("cpu").contiguous().view(-1)
     
        iou_per_class = []
        for clas in range(0, n_classes): #loop per pixel class
            true_class = pred_mask == clas
            true_label = mask == clas
  
            if true_label.long().sum().item() == 0: #no exist label in this loop
                iou_per_class.append(np.nan)
            else:
                intersect = torch.logical_and(true_class, true_label).sum().float().item()
                union = torch.logical_or(true_class, true_label).sum().float().item()

                iou = (intersect + smooth) / (union + smooth)
                iou_per_class.append(iou)
        return np.nanmean(iou_per_class)

def evaluation(dataloader):
  miou = []
  deeplab.load_state_dict(torch.load("/content/drive/MyDrive/best_model1"))
  deeplab.eval()
  with torch.no_grad():
    for image, label in dataloader:
      X_batch = image.to(device).float()
      y_batch = label.to(device)
      preds = deeplab(X_batch)
      _ , predictions = torch.max(preds, dim=1)
      iou_score = mIoU(predictions , y_batch)
      miou.append(iou_score)
  
  score = np.array(miou)
  

  return np.mean(score)
```

Comment: Take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/IvLabs/stagewise-knowledge-distillation/issues/12). The method mentioned by the issue-poster is the one that is usually followed in literature and it will not lead to different mIoU when using different batch sizes (whereas your method which is the one I had used in that repo will).

Answer (score -1):

Batch size matters only through the training process, if you haven't specified batch_input_shape on your first layer (it's from Keras, idk how its done in Torch) you are free to input any batch of data for evaluation/inference. Batch size is used to optimize memory usage sometimes and to make the training process more "flexible" for data (i.e. batch size regulate the number of NN's weights updates through the epoch).

**So, it doesn't matter in inference process**